# gdal.RasterizeLayer() not outputting a proper geotiff file

Tags: python, raster, gdal, ogr, gdal-rasterize

I am trying to rasterize a geodataframe of a vector by burning the attribute values onto a template raster. I can't however get my function to output a proper .tiff file. rather it outputs a regular empty file when I call it.
My functions parameters are:

1)input_gdf: A geodataframe of the shapefile.
2)output_tiff: Name of the output raster as a string
3)cellSize= whatever cell size user wants it to be.(I am passing through 1000 in this case)
4)field_name= False
My code is as follows:

'''
def rasterize(input_gdf, output_tiff, cellSize, field_name=False):
wrkdir= 'C:'
os.chdir(wrkdir)
# Define pixel_size and NoData value of new raster
pixel_size = cellSize
NoData_value = -9999

```
#input_gdf to shapefile conversion:
input_gdf.to_file('clipped.shp')
#now there is a shapefile name of clipped.shp in the wrkdir
#filename of raster tiff that will be created
output_shp= output_tiff

#open the data source/input and read in the extent
source_ds=ogr.Open('clipped.shp')
lyr=source_ds.GetLayer(0)
#inp_srs = lyr.GetSpatialRef()
'''
#Checking if shapefile was loaded properly
if source_ds:
    lyr=source_ds.GetLayer(0)
    inp_srs = lyr.GetSpatialRef()
    print("shapefile loaded")
    print(lyr)
    print(inp_srs)
else:
    print("couldn't load shapefile")

#Extents
x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = lyr.GetExtent(0)
x_res = int((x_max - x_min) / pixel_size)
y_res = int((y_max - y_min) / pixel_size)

#create the destination data source
output_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(output_shp, x_res, y_res, 1, gdal.GDT_Int16)
#if os.path.exists(output_shp):
    #output_ds.Delete(output_shp)
#output_source = out_driver.Create(output_tiff, x_res, y_res, 0, gdal.GDT_Int16)
output_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixel_size, 0, y_max, 0, -pixel_size))
band = output_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
band.SetNoDataValue(NoData_value)
#Rasterization
if field_name:
    gdal.RasterizeLayer(output_ds, [1], lyr, options=["ATTRIBUTE=CT"].format(field_name))
    print("write:",field_name)
else:
    gdal.RasterizeLayer(output_ds, [1], lyr, burn_values=[2])
    
# Save and/or close the data sources
source_ds = None
output_ds = None

# Return
return gdal.Open(output_shp)
```

''''
This is what I am passing through to call the function. Clipped is a geodataframe:

rasterize(clipped, "tiff_file" , 1000, field_name=False)

Comment: Do you get the same result if you save the clipped.shp into disk and run https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html?